# How do I add searchview that utilizes Google Places APS search to Android Map v2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android app that uses Google Maps v2 and I would like to add a searchview that will get results like on the Google Maps app.  I know I must do this using the Google Places API, but I have not located a good example.  I am building my app for Jelly Bean (Android 4.3), so I would like an up to date example.

Comment: refer the links http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog   http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/

Comment: Are you looking to add a search bar to your ActionBar (not ActionBarSherlock but the new ActionBar introduced in 4.1) or do you want a separate SearchView?

Comment: I'm looking to add search to the action bar, not Sherlock action bar.  And only when my map fragment us selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following link for serach in google maps.

The first one provides the  Autocomplete textview with search

Second one is search in google maps with use of ActionBarSherlock library

[Search in google maps](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-google-places-autocomplete-api-as-custom-suggestions-in-android-search-dialog/)

[search in google maps with ABS](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-searchview-widget-with-google-places-api-using-actionbarsherlock-library/)